# Codingbat Array2 zeroMax

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, max

> Return a version of the given array where each zero value in the array is replaced by the largest odd value to the right of the zero in the array. If there is no odd value to the right of the zero, leave the zero as a zero.

```
public int[] zeroMax(int[] nums) {

  int max = 0;
  int temp = 0;

  for(int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++){
    if(nums[i] == 0){
      for(int j = i+1; j < nums.length; j++){
        if(nums[j] % 2 != 0) max = Math.max(HERE, nums[j]); 
      }nums[i] = max; 
      max = 0;
    }
  }
  return nums;
}
```

That's my code for the problem, the HERE is what I don't quite understand. I have to put max there, but in my mind, I would have the possibility to also just put 0 there. Because the loop resets max to 0 anyways, right? But when I put 0 there the code doesn't work for some cases. 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
max = Math.max( max, nums[j] );
```

This code will take the larger of the two: `max` or `nums[j]`.

```
max = Math.max( 0, nums[j] );
```

This code will take any positive `nums[j]` (since it's larger than 0).
Keep in mind that this is in a loop. `max` will be constantly updating to hold the largest number. It will only reset once the loop is done.